Relationship between equation of integral dependence of an element and its inverse
Let $A$ be a reduced, Noetherian ring. Let $B$ be its integral closure. Let $b\in B$ and let $v\in B$ be its inverse. Let $b^n+\ldots a_0=0$ be an equation of integral dependence for $b$. Is there any way to write the equation of integral dependence for $v$ in terms of the equation of integral dependence for $b$?
I cannot seem to find this anywhere and have heard that perhaps the relationship between the equations of integral dependence has something to do with symmetric polynomials.

Is $v \in B$ an assumption?  Usually the inverse of an element in the integral closure will not itself be in the integral closure.  If it is, then $a_0$ is a unit and so you can just write $m_v(t) = a_0^{-1} t^n m_b(t^{-1})$.

In general, $a_0$ might not be invertible. For example, $b^2 + b - 2 = 0$ is a (needlessly convoluted but perfectly valid) integral dependence equation for $1$. So the question might be: If $a_0$ is not invertible, then can we reduce the equation to a smaller one?
